# Принадлежность VolumeID к InstanceID [cloudwatch-exporter]

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus

Через prometheus cloudwatch exporter вытянули метрику `aws_ebs_burst_balance_minimum{job="aws_ebs",instance="",volume_id="vol-0692443b3429d1f",} 99.0 1588671900000`
К сожалению, не возможно понять к каком инстансу данное блочное устр-во присоедино.Каким образом можно сопоставить volume_id и instance_id или какое-то другое решение?